# "Вечером(,) в тот же день воскресения(,) они возвращались в город." Надо ли обособлять?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, обстоятельство

- Факультативно ли выделение, а если нет, то какая конструкция обособляется?

Comment: Во втором источнике из ссылок, данным М_Г, Воскресение дано с прописной, и это правильно. Воскресение — это не воскресенье.

Answer (score 1):

Вечером, **в тот же день воскресения**, они возвращались в город.

Меду двумя обстоятельствами времени могут быть **неоднородные или уточняющие отношения,** и это авторский выбор. Однако окончательное решение зависит от **структуры предложения** (и эту структуру также выбирает автор, когда пишет текст).

В данном случае **обособление обязательно,** так как из этих  обстоятельств сложно составить одну фразу, и поэтому  предложение без обособления  "не читается".

Сравнить: **В тот же день вечером** // они возвращались в город (неоднородные обстоятельства).

Answer (score 1):

Вот результаты моих поисков в Интернете.
Фраза "Вечером в тот же день воскресения" найдена 2 раза, оба раза без запятой:

[Библия для детей](https://books.google.com/books?id=qUY4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT451&lpg=PT451&dq=%22%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC,%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&source=bl&ots=9S5YswqE47&sig=kXWyaz55eazfY79I2ggQWFmndj4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8yOGKnO7YAhVFCsAKHWdvC5AQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&f=false)

[Детская библия в классических иллюстрациях](https://books.google.com/books?id=_A9UqZzepCYC&pg=PA307&lpg=PA307&dq=%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC,%20%22%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&source=bl&ots=-mcyS0IkkI&sig=EhCiC2AZCyE8ONsu4kQkVaCIQAQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw5836m-7YAhUJK8AKHZ8ODXUQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%22%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&f=false)

Думаю, нужно во главу угла поставить смысл фразы. Важно то, что события происходили вечером того же дня, "в тот же день воскресения" не может рассматриватьса как уточнение.

В Нацкорпусе "Вечером, в тот же день воскресения" не найдено, но "вечером в тот же день" найдено несколько десятков раз, запятой почти нигде нет.

Пример: Но вечером в тот же день он явился в штаб бойскаутов и разругался с нами. [Л. А. Кассиль. Кондуит и Швамбрания (1928-1931)]

Comment: "Вечером в тот же день" можно не обособлять,  фраза короткая. Но увеличьте объем  второго обстоятельства, и обособление будет необходимым, никакой смысл не поможет, например: "Вечером,  в тот же день этого незабываемого воскресного дня..."

Comment: Как заметил @shampar, речь идет не о воскресном дне, а о дне Воскресения. По-моему, это усиливает мою позицию.

Comment: Нет разницы, обособление зависит от объема и структуры оборота. К примеру, можно не обособлять: Вечером того же дня Воскресения/воскресения...